# Using \label command in a custom command

Tags: macros, cross-referencing

I have some big equations that I wanted to separate out of the text of my document to make the source code easier to read.  The idea was to declare a command for each equation in a separate file, include the file in the preamble of my document, and then just call the command for that equation in the appropriate place in the text.  Here's a single-file example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\testCommand}{
    \begin{equation} \label{eq1}
        a = b + c
    \end{equation}
}

\begin{document}
    \testCommand
    \cite{eq1}
\end{document}
```

The problem with this is that I get undefined reference errors when I try to cite the equation.  I'm assuming that the compiler must go through and find labels before it expands commands or something.  Anyway, I was just wondering if there is a way to make this work.  I would also appreciate some insight on what's going on under the hood that causes this to happen.

Comment: Don't do this; say `\newcommand{\myweirdeq}{a=b+c}` and use `\begin{equation}\label{eq1}\myweirdeq\end{equation}`, so your document will be correctly marked up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to cite a `\label` is with `\ref`; `\cite` is for bibliographies.

Comment: Wow, duh.  Don't know why my mind randomly got set on `\cite`.  I guess that's what happens when you haven't used LaTeX much for a while.  Now I feel sheepish. =)  Also, what's the appropriate thing to do with the question in this case?  Should it be closed, deleted, or just left as it is?

Comment: @Brandon: No upside in deleting it. I am sure you are not the only one who will make this mistake.  I have had a few embarrassing questions myself, so don't worry about it.

Comment: @Brandon: As further evidence that this question should stay: I have done this myself.  A lot.