# Custom command does not reference a label created with a previous custom command

Tags: macros, floats

Using pdfLaTeX. I have created a new command

```
\newcommand{\singlefigure}[3]{
  \begin{figure}
  \label{fig:#2}
  \centering
  \caption{#3}
  \includegraphics[trim={0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm},clip,height=0.2\textheight]{./fig/#1}
  \end{figure}
}
```

having it in mind to speed up the coding of figures. Actually it suits me pretty well, at first since

```
\singlefigure{directory/file.jpg}{mylabel}{My caption}
```

gets me immediately where I want.

---

Likewise, I have created another shorthand to reference a figure

```
\newcommand{\fig}[1]{Figure~\ref{fig:#1}}
```

which works well except when I am referencing a figure created with `\singlefigure` above, say `\fig{mylabel}`.

---

The result is

[image]

Apparently I created a situation in which the label of the first command is not visible to the second one. Is there a remedy, correction or workaround for this glitch?

---

Similar posts:

- [How can I refer to label created by new command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84445/how-can-i-refer-to-label-created-by-new-command)
- [Using \label command in a custom command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62364/using-label-command-in-a-custom-command)

Comment: The first time that you compile a document with a new `\ref` command you will get `??`. When you compile the document a second time the reference appears. If this is not your problem then rather than posting code fragments please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228), which compiles, so that people can replicate your problem. Btw, rather then defining`\fig` you might want to use `\autoref` from [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) or `\cref` from [cleveref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref).

Comment: The `\label` must _always_ come after the `\caption`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for the tip. This is indeed the answer, and I am glad that this post is now linked to that.